# Trackpad troubleshooting on MacBook air 2019

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad

Recently after switching from a 2015 MacBook air to 2019...I have been frustrated a lot. A few days ago, my trackpad randomly stopped clicking things. The cursor was moving around fine, but I was unable to click and drag anything. As a final course of action, I had to force restart my computer, which returns the trackpad back to its normal working condition. Just today, my laptop was on sleep for a while (the lid was closed). Later, I opened my laptop up, and to my surprise, it was not just the clicking issue but the whole damn trackpad. I wasn't able to move the cursor, swipe to other desktops etc. I decided to see if, I get the controls back by connecting my laptop to my mouse and it did work. So, I deduce the issue is certainly with the trackpad.
After a few minutes, I decided to see if I get back my trackpad after closing the lid and finally it works.

Anyways, with all these trackpad troubleshooting issues I mentioned above, 
does anyone notice a trend? Do I have to be concerned about anything? Should I visit the apple store?

Comment: If you're concerned about hardware on a new machine (within warrantee, statutory limits, etc), then you should take it back to the shop.

Comment: okay...I probably would consider it if it happens once again.